# Is there any way in excel to show last line of a cell when we reduce height?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am wondering if there is any method or function to show last line when we reduce the height.

Let's say in a cell there are three lines.

```
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
```

When I reduce height, it shows "This is line 1", whereas I am looking for solution to show "This is line 3."

Comment: `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B5,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",200)),200))` might be a solution for you. Check the [Get last line in cell](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-last-line-in-cell) article to understand the formula.

Comment: Cell content has alignment choices both horizontally and vertically.  If you set the vertical alignment to bottom-aligned, line 3 will be visible, and whatever doesn't fit of lines 1 and 2 will be cut off at the top of the cell.  If you want to see everything, you can use a combination of making the column wider, or leaving the column to the right empty so content spills over, if you can word-wrap the cell contents, and/or using a smaller font (or "narrow" font if you can word-wrap).

Comment: @Ronaldo, Thanks for the solution. It is working fine however my team is looking solution in the same cell.

Comment: @Fixer1234, Thanks for your reply. I tried with your solution however seems bug in Microsoft Excel, it shows second line not last line.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have ready access to Excel to troubleshoot.  I normally use LO Calc, and it works in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I would like to suggest one simple & tricky method to you.*

[image]

- Now reduce the Row height.

[image]

- Hit the Formula Bar.

[image]

- Now using the Arrow Button move Up & Down to reach to the Line.
  [image]

**N.B.**

- If you want to extract Last Line, you have to use Formula suggested by #Ronaldo through comments.

Comment: This is weekly excel sheet and looking in many cells like this is time consuming.

Comment: @DamanjeetSingh,, I think it's the only possible simplest method,, as you brought the issue,, otherwise you may use the Formula suggested by #Ronaldo, through comments!!

Comment: @DamanjeetSingh,, as an alternative I may suggest VBA macro,, to automate the process & save time but you need to [Edit] your question and add line that you also needVBA   and Add VBA Tag too with question!

Comment: Glad to help you @DamanjeetSingh,, keep asking ☺

Comment: Later versions of Excel seem to all have the bug where if you bottom align, regardless of the number of lines, it shows line 2 instead of the last line. There's no "at a glace" solution to solve this for a whole page. You can however pin the formula bar an drag it to as many lines as you want, which means it will display the entire contents of the selected cell

Comment: My only suggestion is to create second page linked to the first with every cell displaying the last line of the corresponding cell on the first page. That way all the info is still there on the first page for the rest of the team and you can look at the last lines only on the second page when you need to

Answer (score -1):

I have the same question but I don't think a formula will help because I don't want to extract the information from the last line I just want the last line to be displayed and everything above the last line to fade away above. Has anyone found a solution to this bug yet?

Comment: Try not to answer with the same question